# Show title in ListTile when Text widget is not null

Tags: flutter

I'm working on an alarm project. In my list of alarms the description is shown as the title and the time is shown as subtitle. I only want to see the alarm time when no description is given.My issue is I can't hide the subtitle when there is no description. Can someone help me out? Thx!

```
ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  (alarm.description != null)
                      ? '${alarm.description}'
                      : '${formatDate(alarm.time, [HH, ':', nn])}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  (alarm.description != null)
                      ? '${formatDate(alarm.time, [HH, ':', nn])}'
                      : '',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                ),
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Marc! Weirdly, your code seems very reasonable to me. What exactly is happening with that code? Does it always show the description on the title an nothing on the subtitle or what?

Comment: Hi George thanks for your contribution. The subtitle field was an empty space in the card. With the null return Emmanuel suggests, it is like not invoking the property at start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the subtitle property you firstly check if the description is not null, then pass it the `Text` Widget if it's not, else you can pass `null` like so

```
ListTile(
  title: Text(
    (alarm.description != null) ? '${alarm.description}' : '${formatDate(alarm.time, [HH, ':', nn])}',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
  ),
  subtitle: (alarm.description != null)
      ? Text(
          '${formatDate(alarm.time, [HH, ':', nn])}',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
        )
      : null,
),
```

Hope it helped you :)

Comment: That's right, and you could simplify a little the first text using the `??` operator like this: `'${alarm.description ?? formatDate(alarm.time, [HH,':',nn])}'`

Comment: Pablo I like the title simplification you suggest.